# Как получить права при помощи ActivityCompat.requestPermissions из сервиса

Tags: java, android

Как получить права при помощи ActivityCompat.requestPermissions из сервиса, его нужно получать из Actyvity как я понял

Нужно получать права напрямую командой с ссылкой на активити или вызывать метод в активити?

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(???, Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW);
```

Answer (score 3):

Напрямую никак. Возможный механизм обхода:

1. В сервисе проверяете, есть ли пермишн.
2. Если нет, создаёте локальный пуш.
3. При клике на пуш открываете `Activity`, где уже можно будет запросить пермишн.

Comment: Так а как создать вообще что либо если нет прав?

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров для локальных пушей права дополнительные разве нужны?